# Bing Maps Rest Services Multiple Locations for Geocoding

Tags: geocoding, bing-maps

Currently, I have an ASP application which retrieves a set of locations from a datasource and then uses Bing map REST services to geocode the addresses and then display them on a table and a map in pages of 10 results at a time.
Currently,  the application processes the locations sequentially ...

```
    var geocodeRequest = "http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" + fullAddress.replace('&', ' ').replace(',', ' ') + "?output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + getCredentials;
    CallRestService(geocodeRequest);

    ......

    function GeocodeCallback(result) {
        if (result &&
                       result.resourceSets &&
                       result.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
                       result.resourceSets[0].resources &&
                       result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {

            // Set the map view using the returned bounding box
            var bbox = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].bbox;
            var viewBoundaries = MM.LocationRect.fromLocations(new MM.Location(bbox[0], bbox[1]), new MM.Location(bbox[2], bbox[3]));
            map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries });

            // Add a pushpin at the found location
            MM.Location.prototype.locID = null;
            var location = new MM.Location(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0], result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[1]);
            location.locID = tableRowIndex;
            locs.push(location);

.....
```

Is there any way to speed this up by passing 10 locations in one call and then processing result.resourceSets[0], result.resourceSets[1] etc?
How would multiple addresses be passed into the rest services call? (comma deliminated?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bing has two REST-accessible geocoding APIs.  One of them is the one you're using, which only supports one address at a time, and the other is the [Dataflow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx) which is designed for high-volume batch processing.  Neither really seem like they're right for you, as your system is currently designed.

Depending on where you're getting your street addresses from (all you mention is 'a datasource'), you might be able to do a big-batch geocode for all the locations in your datasource - move the geocoding from request time to a batch process, and just use the request-time geocoding for the ones the batch process hasn't gotten to yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this as it looks right now. It has been proposed to support native in javascript (i think), but I do not think that it has been implemented yet. It you want some concurrency, you could look at webworkers:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers

But this is not supported in IE yet. Maybe you could try to check out html5 async. I do not know if it could be used in the creation of the script element that is created when you call the REST services.